# Integrating watson chatbot with slack without usernane and password

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-conversation, botkit

I am new to Watson Assistant and to BotKit. I was trying to create a chatbot and integrate it with Slack, but botkit needs a "conversation username" and "conversation password" to integrate with Watson Assistent. However I only have the Watson Assistant API, so how can I use it in botkit?

Comment: Please look at guide [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Didn't that work? https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/botkit-middleware

Comment: Watson Assistant is a new name of Watson Conversation.

Answer (score 0):

When you create your Watson Assistant service, you can go into it and select the credentials page.

There you can create a username/password for your botkit app.

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: Have you created your service?

Comment: yes I have, but I don't know how to write my username/password as a credential when I create a new one